# Inserting data properly in to sqlite database

Tags: iphone, sqlite, insert

I am developing an app that contains a view controller,where the user fills all the fields and when he clicks save,the data must get inserted in to the database.I am able to retrieve the primary key (id) for every reminder saved.But I am unable to insert data,as when I am trying to display it in console,it's displaying null.Please post the correct and relevant code of my requirement to save the data in to created table in database.

It's my humble request to post the code for performing an action in such a way that when I click save,the data must get inserted in to the table of database.I would be pretty glad If I can see the code for retrieval of data to display in the other controller(page) "View/Edit Reminder"...Please help me out.I tried all the ways,I have gone through 100's of solutions.

[retrieved data from sqlite database and displaying it on grouped table view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040818/retrieved-data-from-sqlite-database-and-displaying-it-on-grouped-table-view)

[Sqlite iPhone data insertion problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666113/sqlite-iphone-data-insertion-problem)

[how to insert value from one table to other table in sqlite3 database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415604/how-to-insert-value-from-one-table-to-other-table-in-sqlite3-database)

[SQLite3 database doesn't actually insert data - iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785211/sqlite3-database-doesnt-actually-insert-data-iphone)

[Why does SQLite not bring back any results from my database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155691/why-does-sqlite-not-bring-back-any-results-from-my-database)

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/adding-data-using-sqlite-for-iphone/

etc... etc... Please make me get out of this problem

Comment: I'm just curious: any reason for not using core data ?

Comment: @HeikoG Actually I am not aware of core data,as we are suggested to use sqlite for storing and retrieving database

Comment: Im just asking because most of the time core data would probably be the better choice and saves lots of time. Besides : with core data you are still using SQLite behind the scenes. Just have a look here http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the answer of this question:
[Storing and retrieving data from sqlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147519/storing-and-retrieving-data-from-sqlite-database/8147921#8147921)

It shows how to connect to a database, insert a new record, and retrieve an old one.

Answer (score 0):

Check Out this link:-

[how to insert only one username and password in sqlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178011/how-to-insert-only-one-username-and-password-in-sqlite-database/8178682#8178682)

I have explain two method first is how to read from a table and second how to write inside the database.Just before calling any of these methods you have to call the method checkandCreateDatabase.